# If $\vec A=\frac12\vec B$, doesn't that imply that the magitude of$\vec A$ is also half of the magnitude of $\vec B$?

Tags: calculus, vectors

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOHgY.png

In the last section of this example in my Vector Calculus textbook, the authors imply that $\overrightarrow{M_1M_2}=\frac12\overrightarrow{BC}$ only implies that they are parallel and nothing about magnitudes. They even explicitly state that the magnitudes are equal afterwards by a different proposition. So is it true that vectors being a fraction of other vectors do not imply the same proportionality for their magnitudes?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If the proportion is positive, then the magnitudes will be in the same proportion.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Aren't they also using $\vec{M_1M_2}=\frac12\vec{BC}$ in conjuction with that different proposition to show moreover that the magnitudes are equal ?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\vec{A}=k\vec{B}$. Then each component $A_i$ in $\vec{A}$ is equal to $kB_i$ with $k\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $$  \left\lVert\vec{A}\right\rVert=\sqrt{k^2B_1^2 + k^2B_2^2+...+k^2B_n^2}=|k|\sqrt{B_1^2+B_2^2+...+B_n^2}=|k|\left\lVert\vec{B}\right\rVert$$   So yes, if one vector is proportional to another, then their magnitudes are proportional by the same factor.

Also, if $2$ vectors are proportional to each other, then they are linearly dependent and therefore parallel to each other. I am not sure which proposition they refer to either.